# How to catch run time error in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, runtime-error

Like modifying a `CONST int`,

Can I register a specific function to handle run time errors so that this kind of operation just fails instead of terminating the application?

Comment: That is a little bit of a bad example - `const` is purely a compiler directive, and has no guarantee of working,failing or causing an error if you manage to get around the restriction using unsafe type casting. No compiler I know of "remembers" the `const` restriction at runtime...

Comment: @tobyodavies: I think it's a good example if that's what the OP is asking about. :) The type information may not exist at runtime any more, but the object is still non-mutable, semantically, as the program runs. That doesn't just go away!

Comment: @Tomalak, yes it does in C if the int happens to be stored on the stack, you won't get a SIGSEGV or any other kind of runtime error unless the compiler has managed to allocate it in a protected area of memory which is not possible in general

Answer (score 7):

If you mean C++, there is a certain exception class called `runtime_error`. You can catch it with a catch clause:

```
catch(std::runtime_error& e) {}
```

However, many things in C and C++ (like modifying a const int) result in [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can't catch them at runtime. You can't catch them, because no exception is thrown (technically, anything may happen, including a throwing of exception (C++ only), but that's not something you can or should hope for).

The solution is to write clean safe code. For that there are many advices listed in many books. :)

Comment: You can handle a lot of errors (like divide by zero) in C and C++ either with exceptions or signal handlers. Though modifying a `const` is obviously not one of them. Doing so helps in the whole reliable code department sometimes too especially if you are dealing with plugins or other 3rd party code...

Comment: @tobyodavies: Portably - you can't, can you?

Comment: Posix is portable enough in my experience. Truely portable, nontrivial and C are usually a rare combination.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying a `const` is, according to the specification, "undefined behavior" so the compiler can do anything.  In practice, many implementations **sometimes** generate runtime errors for such code but many do not.  It often depends on the nature of the program.  Here is an illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*fn)(const char *);

extern const fn global_fn_ptr;
extern const char global_string[];
const fn global_fn_ptr = puts;
const char global_string[] = "hello";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Setting global_fn_ptr to NULL");
    *(fn *)&global_fn_ptr = NULL;
    puts("Setting string to \"bye\"");
    strcpy((char *)global_string, "bye");
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, I get a SIGBUS from modifying the string, but modifying the function works fine.  This is due to the peculiar nature of function pointers, whose value is not always determined at runtime so the value must be stored in writable memory.

It is generally not safe to catch a SIGBUS or SIGSEGV in C++ and turn it into an exception.  It is also very difficult to correctly `longjmp` out of a signal handler — half the code that uses this pattern in C is probably incorrect.  The safest option is to let the program terminate immediately, or if you really need this kind of help from the runtime, work very carefully with C code so you can free the appropriate resources in a nonlocal exit — C++ won't do because `longjmp` won't call destructors.

Or you can just move to C# or Java, both of which have runtimes that do this for you and garbage collectors that clean up afterwards.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the reference to the section of C99 that says that modifying a const is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pete: Hm, why do you say it won't compile?  It compiles successfully on my computer, it doesn't even generate warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` using `clang` or `gcc` (except "unused parameter", which is noise).  The global string has type `char const[6]` and static storage duration, which means that it has six bytes of space permanently allocated for it.  (Are you thinking of `char *`?)  As I explained in the thread where you asked for a reference, see n1570 §6.7.3.6.  I can't always answer Stack Overflow questions during the day so please be patient.

Comment: "Or you can just move to C# or Java, both of which have runtimes that do this for you and garbage collectors that clean up afterwards." Any non antique OS too has garbage collectors which will handle crashes. A language doesn't need it's own garbage collector for security.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam: The garbage collector is there as part of a system to provide memory safety. Asking whether something is "needed" for security is probably the wrong question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is operating system specific. The language itself specifies these as undefined behaviour.

In POSIX-compliant operating systems your program can catch a `SIGSEGV` signal in case of a restricted memory access, `SIGILL` in case of an invalid instruction or `SIGFPE` in case of an illegal floating point operation, for example division by zero.

Comment: You should probably note the need for setjmp/longjmp in the signal handlers - it is not safe to do a normal return after catching a signal from a program error

Comment: @tobyodavies: aren't most kernels killing the offending process after the signal handler is executed anyway?

Comment: @tobyodavies ,can you provide a specific case that's `not safe to do a normal return after catching a signal from a program error` ?

Comment: @R__ http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Program-Error-Signals.html#Program-Error-Signals 4th paragraph. Intuitively what happens if you return from the `SIGFPE` handler in the statement `return 1/0;`? it doesn't make sense and is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In C runtime errors generally generate signals that can be handled by signal handlers.

In C++ runtime errors can also be thrown as exceptions that can be caught in a try/catch block.

To continue at some point rather than crashing, you will need to use setjmp/longjmp in the signal handlers - it is not safe to return after catching a signal from a program error

Comment: "In C++ runtime errors are generally thrown as exceptions and can be caught in a try/catch block." Are they? :)))

Comment: depends on the definition of "runtime error" - divide by zero isn't, but exceptions are thrown for other errors that, if uncaught, will still halt program execution. This classes as a runtime error in my book...

Comment: going out of bounds of an array, modifying a const object, dereferencing a pointer to a variable gone out of scope - and you say MOST of the things throw exceptions? :)

Answer (score 1):

**I was quite wrong.**

Trying to modify a const-qualified variable is indeed undefined behavior and, it appears, has been so for some years. It might or might not generate a run-time error; whether it does or not depends on the platform.

[**n1570**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which is the committee draft for the next iteration of the C standard, gives the rule in section 6.7.3, as @Dietrich Epp patiently pointed out. The wording in that section probably hasn't changed since C89.

I'm extremely sorry for claiming otherwise; and for insulting members of this group. Especially Dietrich.

Now, where can I find some of that delicious, free-range crow?

Comment: You can modify a const if you create a pointer to it and cast away a const. As for whether a runtime error occurs is based on whether it's a file-scope or block-scope variable. Obviously, if it is defined locally on the stack, it can be overwritten because it cannot be made read only at the hardware level (the lowest granularity of access control is per page). For const file-scope variables, they are stored in .rodata which will be on a read only page of its own. You should get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You must know this and it must be that your example is ill considered, but it's worthwhile noting anyway in case somebody gets the wrong idea:

In C, there's no such thing as a `const int` (or `const` anything else) at ***run time***; `const` is purely a ***compile-time*** notion. Thus there's no run-time error for modifying a `const int`.

Comment: Modifying a `const int` is "undefined behavior" according to the C spec.  Many implementations will catch it at runtime and raise SIGBUS or SIGSEGV.

Comment: @Pete that was an example, and a poorly chosen one. Though since the behavior is undefined, a runtime error _could_ occur in theory...

Comment: @Pete: From n1570: §6.7.3.6: "If an attempt is made to modify an object deﬁned with a const-qualiﬁed type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualiﬁed type, the behavior is undeﬁned."

Comment: I don't think that this is an answer.

Comment: @tobyodavies -- Modifying a variable marked as const in the source file is ***not*** undefined behavior. If you still claim it is, please give us a reference to the section in C99 that backs up that claim.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp -- Hmmmmmmm. n1570 certainly says just that. I might have to back down. But not quite yet :-) There's no part of n869 that even contemplates such a crazy restriction. Thanks so much for giving the reference, Dietrich.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the scenarios that you are talking about are those that (generally) are *undefined* according to the language.

These scenarios lead to unpredictable results and, as you've noted, these results can sometimes include the program continuing and appearing to "work", or it can crash, or nasal demons can spontaneously come into existence.

If you want to catch the use of undefined behaviour then you can do this *in some situations*, using tools.

For example, [Electric Fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence) is great at revealing where you're writing to memory that you shouldn't be (though don't activate it in release builds!). Whether this will work for writing to something whose `const`ness you casted away will depend on what optimisations have been applied; it's possible that the object *will* have writeable memory, and it'll be physically impossible to determine that you're actually doing something wrong.

What you're not going to get is a tidy language-layer exception. Since you're going to have to go down the tools route anyway, just apply static and dynamic analysis tools as best you can and *profile*. There is no foolproof way to suddenly turn on "sanely inform me of all use of Undefined Behaviour".